# Bitmap font is not working

Tags: java, libgdx

For some reason my bitmap font won't draw when inside this if statement. If I put the font.draw on the outside of the if(correct) it will draw. I confirmed that correct was set to a value of either true or false.

```
if(state == "showingAnswer") {
    if(correct) {
        font.draw(batch, "correct", 340, 460);
    } else {
        font.draw(batch, "incorrect", card.bounds.x + 10, card.bounds.y - 260);
    }
}
```

Comment: "the font.draw" -- there are *two*. The error must be in Code Not Shown. Are you sure the `card.bounds` coordinates are valid, for example?

Comment: I'm looking at `state == "showingAnswer"`... _PLEASE_ change this to `state.equals("showingAnswer")` Java is a *** on that point

Comment: Jongware, card.bounds is used before this font gets drawn and is not changed between the two times. Also, both of them work outside of the if(correct)  I am going to try to make correct a string since the state if statements are working

Answer (score 0):

It was drawing off screen.  I don't know how it drew the other stuff just fine, but that was the problem.